# Why my handler runs only once to refresh data

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and I am developing an app that fetch current rate from bitrex and convert it to Indian rupees but the problem is I want to refresh the rate in every  seconds but my Handler runs only one time and did not change its value after first time even if the rates change in the bitrex API

This is my Activity

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {
double last;
double inr;
double x;


TextView tv, tt, ui,uer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);





    uer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.usern);
    ui = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uid);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);


    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    final RequestQueue queuee = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    String url = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=usdt-btc";
    String urll="http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD";

    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    JSONObject json = null;
                    try {
                        json = new JSONObject(response);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        JSONObject result = json.getJSONObject("result");

                        last = result.getDouble("Last");
                        tv.setText(String.valueOf(last));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });


    final StringRequest stringRequestmoney = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urll,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {


                    JSONObject jjson = null;
                    try {
                        jjson = new JSONObject(response);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        JSONObject money = jjson.getJSONObject("rates");
                        inr = money.getDouble("INR");
                        tt.setText(String.valueOf(inr));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });


//        queue.add(stringRequest);
//        queuee.add(stringRequestmoney);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                //do something
                                queue.add(stringRequest);
                                queuee.add(stringRequestmoney);
                                x = (last * inr);     
                                ui.setText(""+x);
                                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);

                            }
                        }, 5000);



}
```

Comment: How do you know the Handler never called again?

Comment: BecauseThe rate changes in the api but did't change in my android application @GeniusQ

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if this is the source of your problem but try to catch any error in you handler

```
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                                try{
                                    //do something
                                    queue.add(stringRequest);
                                    queuee.add(stringRequestmoney);
                                    x = (last * inr);     
                                    ui.setText(""+x);
                                    handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
                          }
                       finally {
                       // 100% guarantee that this always happens, even if
                       // your update method throws an exception
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
                                 }
                                }
                            }, 5000);
```

Comment: Unable to find any problem in code. M i writing anything wrong in handler ? @Boukharist